# How to prevent TrigReduce auto evaluating Sin and Cos

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica automatically evaluates `Sin` and `Cos` when `TrigReduce` is applied. For example, `TrigReduce[Cos[2*t]*Cos[2*t]]` results in `1/2 (1 + Cos[4 t])`. In my application I would like `TrigReduce` to keep the `Sin` and `Cos` as is. I'd like to have `1/2 (Cos[0 t] + Cos[4 t])` as the output of the preceding example. I tried to use `Inactivate`, but that seems to prevent `TrigReduce` from working as well.

Comment: I have thousands of large expressions that needed to trigReduce. Finding the patterns is nearly impossible.  The only way(except writing my own TrigReduce functions) I can think of is to prevent it from evaluating the terms.

Comment: Can you replace `Cos` with `myCos`, use `TrigReduce`, then replace `myCos` with `Cos` ?

Comment: Best would be to write a targeted function for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way:

```
    expr1 = Cos[2*t]^2 /. Cos[2 t]^2 :> Cos[(2 + x)*t]*Cos[2 t]

(*  Cos[2 t] Cos[t (2 + x)]   *)
```

Then

```
expr2 = TrigReduce@expr

(*   1/2 (Cos[2 t - t (2 + x)] + Cos[2 t + t (2 + x)])  *)
```

Now we can simplify the subexpressions under the `Cos` sighs, and replace `tx` by `HoldForm[0]` and `x` - by `0`:

```
MapAt[Simplify, expr2, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}] /. 
  t x -> HoldForm[0] /. x -> 0
```

yielding

[image]

I have no idea how your other terms look like. Therefore, I cannot garanty that it will work for the whole your complex expression. However, you can try to invent something along this line.

Please do not forget that `HoldForm[0]` cannot be operated by Mma functions. If you need to further operate with the result, apply first `ReleaseHold`.

Have fun!